# Can't input value in malloc Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

So I need to create dynamic size matrix and I need to use malloc because maximum size of it has to be 10 000. I tryied something like that:

```
double *matrix =malloc(rowCount * colCount * sizeof (double));
```

and I am adding values to this matrix using this:

```
for (i =0;i<rowCount;i++){
        for (j=0;j<colCount;j++){
            matrix[i* colCount+j]=(double)i;    
        }
    }
```

but when I want to get values using this:

```
for (i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
            for(j=0;j<colCount;j++){
                printf("%d",matrix[i*colCount+j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

all I get is 0 at all positions.
Anyone could help me and tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `printf("%d")` for `double`? Try reading the documentation for `printf()`.

Comment: If you had turned on warnings for your compiler, you would have been warned that %d was wrong.  For gcc I use `-Wall -pedantic` and it helps me no end, especially being new to C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%d` isn't for printing floats.  You want `%f`

If you're on a platform with 32-bit ints and 64-bit doubles, your code is printing a portion of your float that is entirely 0's.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format